# Place Picker automatically closing despite the (("com.google.android.geo.API_KEY")) in manifests

Tags: android, google-maps, gmsplacepicker

I am developing travel application.
In Main Activity My app has one Google map and uses Google API .
And I want use the Place Picker at other Activity. 
But Place picker closes immediately ((Famous Problem)).
I change My Manifest but It did't Solve.

Please help It's very important for me.

I think it because of I can`t use one API twice (1. Google map 2.Place Picker).

How can I solve it?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you are right Just place "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
Remove any other keys from AndroidManifest.

Comment: How can I have 2 API ?
or 
How can I use map and place picker in one application with one api?

Comment: It will be okay to use just one

Comment: Fine
But I need Both of them 1. google Map 2. Place picker 
What can I do?

Comment: I have just one key in manifest .
Google Map work well
But Place Picker not

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: ohh that is old version plz try with new

Comment: Tnx
I am going to try it